# using signal in c and resuming from specific point in program

Tags: c, linux, signals, sigint

I'm writing a program where I need to catch `SIGINT` signal so that I can kill child processes without the parent process exiting. I can kill child processes by sending them `SIGKILL`.

But after a signal is handled the main program resumes from where it left off.  I want it to resume from somewhere else.  For example say I have a loop and a signal is caught somewhere within loop; after handling the signal I want the program to resume from the beginning of the loop, rather than the middle.

Comment: I your example when you resume from handling the signal you can use "continue" and initialize your loop condition. i.e. for while (i<threshold) write continue; i=0;

Answer (score 2):

It lies in the nature of asynchronous signals that they can interupt the code at any time.

If there are sections in the code where such an interuption is unwanted then disable signals for those parts.

In all other sections do relevant checks to determine whether an interuption occured and make the code react accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

It's really bad form to catch `SIGINT` and that do anything other than terminate. If you want to intercept the signal so you can kill children, then you should do an and exit -- do NOT continuing your program normally.

In your signal handler, set a global flag that indicates `SIGINT` was received, then from within your loop, test this variable, and execute conditional branch logic.

Comment: How would a `setjmp()` help?

Comment: Instead of returning from handler, he could execute `longjmp()` to just above his loop. This is *REALLY* a bad idea -- but sometimes bad ideas are the only way to get something done.

Comment: Also I know quite a few common programs which on receiving a `SIGINT` do something else but terminate.

Comment: What would happend after the next call to `return`?

Comment: Sure -- doing clean shutdown is OK, but continuing a loop is not likely the right course of action.

Comment: "...*What would happend after the next call to return?...* -- BAD THINGS. It would then return from the signal handler.

Comment: ... and would continue from where left off when receiving the signal. So you gained nothing by the `longjmp()`.

Comment: You're assuming he would return. It's possible he just calls exit(-1)

Comment: But leaving the program is what the OP does not seem to want.

Comment: Tell you what -- I've removed the reference to `setjmp`. It's an advanced use and requires too much special explanation.

Comment: if i jump from signal_handler then it not take/catch signal next time becoz the first  handler has not returned yet....